# response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-control-Allow-Origin' header is present in the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

Our development team is trying to upload the files into S3 with .net and facing

[image]

The S3 bucket is configured with the CORS policy as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Adding the javascript code

```
import React from 'react';
import S3FileUpload from 'react-s3';
 
//Optional Import
import ReactS3, { uploadFile } from 'react-s3';
 
const config = {
    bucketName: 'yellow-pages-bahrain',
   // dirName: 'SPA_Images/Suppliers', /* optional */
    region: 'me-south-1',
    accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
}

function App() {

 const upload = (e) => { 
   
  //console.log(e.target.files);
 // S3FileUpload.uploadFile(e.target.files[0], config)
  //reactS3.uploadFile(e.target.files[0], config)
  ReactS3.uploadFile(e.target.files[0], config)
  .then ((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    alert(err);
  } )

}

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
      <h1>Nks testupload</h1>
      <input 
      type="file"
      onChange={upload}
      />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Could anyone help us out of this.
Not able to figure out how to handle this which is bugging us from days.

Comment: can you post your javascript code that talks to the s3.

Comment: @ArunK I 'll share it as soon as i have it with me. 
Do you feel there is some issues with the code which is trying to upload the file?

Comment: did you type this CORS config manually in staackoverflow. its malformed . the CORSRule ending tag is missing

Comment: No. the first `<CORSRule> ` does not have an ending `<\CORSRule> `. the second `< CORSRule >` is fine.

Comment: @ArunK i was manual error while copying it into stack overflow

Comment: thats what i thought. your cors is fine. try to send your request to the regional endpoint `https://yellow-pages-bahrain.s3-me-south-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: @ArunK i understand now, how can i modify my code to send the request directly to regional endpoint?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220067/discussion-between-arun-k-and-sumanth-shetty).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working perfectly fine for me. I did not get any errors. make sure your code is using the same region as the bucket. Please double check the cors. The following is working fine for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Please note that using aws credentials directly on the html frontend is not recommended. if you would like to upload from frontend, you should use s3 presignedUrls.

[Uploading objects using presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

Comment: this is a bummer , i have that CORS setup and also trying to run the script that is there but i am receiving this error. Could there be any other thing which is causing the issue?

Comment: can we test it with my bucket

Comment: Do you think the issue is with region i.e "me-south-1". Did you use the same region ?

Comment: I have tested in ap-southeast-2

Comment: the same code is working ,The issue was with the region 'me-south-1'

Comment: What region did you put

Comment: replaced 'me-south-1' with 'us-east-1'

Comment: For the same bucket? Then the bucket should be in us-east-1

Comment: no, for a different bucket . created a new bucket with same configuration and different region , then it worked

Comment: I am also trying it with different regions like Australia, Bahrain, Ireland, and  Mumbai but only with 'us-east-1', this seems to be working. Could you happen to know a reason why?

Comment: I have tested with Australia (ap-southeast-2) and worked for me

Comment: ya, but AWS internally must be mapping me to another region.
I am wondering how a same code is working for a bucket of one region and not for others. Is this feature only released to our primary region (us-east-1) for me. It is not a unique feature as well. It should be present in all region.